# Database explorer within a c# program?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, database-connection

I would like to know if there already exist something which does basically the same thing as the data source browser in Visual Studio?

The goal is to provide a way for my administrator to configure the the host-credentials-database using a GUI, which can create a connection-string I can save for further use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [here](http://wildermuth.com/2007/01/29/Using_the_Visual_Studio_Connection_String_D).

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I need, is there a way to make it works without winform? Because it's a wpf app

Comment: It will still work but your Target Framework can't be one of the Client Profile versions. Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

- [EMS SQL Manager](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products)
- [Orion DB](http://www.oriondb.com/)
- [SqlYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/)
- [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need to administrate the database, only to set the host-credentials-database of a connection string

Answer (score 0):

No such thing mate. I am afraid you may need to build one for yourself, I prefer you do it on codeplex (and let it be an opensource project).